# Is there an Android app that pressing on words translates them?

Tags: resources, learning, dictionary, software

I [found](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1653/25265) this popup browser dictionary: [Zhongwen: Chinese-English Dictionary](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/zhongwen-chinese-english/). Hovering the mouse over a character, it displays the translation and the pinyin:

[image]

**Is there an app that gives this easy segmented translation and the pinyin of Chinese characters in Android?**

Currently, I use Google translator but I have to copy every word and open the app for translating, which is not practical and too time-consuming.

---

**Edit disclaimer:** This question was closed and deleted as off-topic, because resources are off-topic on this site. However, I just now found an answer to this question and I believe it could be very useful for other users of this site learning Chinese (e.g. to communicate with other people, read from websites or read ebooks). So I will post it in an answer, I understand if the question is closed again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the [Pleco app](https://www.pleco.com/) manages to do this task using the (free) option `Screen Reader`:

[image]

For example, browsing online in a website:

[image]

If we press on the button
[image], the app recognizes the characters and pressing on any character gives the *pinyin* and the *translation*:

[image]

You can even *listen* to the selected character or the whole text with the corresponding buttons: [image].

From my testings, this function **works fine in Whatsapp, Instagram and Facebook chat**. But it does **not work in Wechat or Facebook posts**.

Answer (score 2):

Now there is also [Langtern](https://langtern.com/), a free iOS and Android app that has an embedded browser with a dictionary that shows the meaning of words you click on.

This is an example with a piece of news from [中国日报](https://cn.chinadaily.com.cn/):

[image]

It works with web pages in general, but also with Youtube video subtitles, with PDF documents, and with e-books in epub format.

[image]
[image]

Full disclosure: I am the creator of Langtern.